# ¿Como obtener el nombre de la ruta no actual en laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo un problema en [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) para obtener el nombre de la ruta no actual. Buscando en la documentación encontré esta función `currentRouteName()` sin embargo éste funciona únicamente para la ruta que se está ejecutando en ese mismo momento.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido Rony, ¿A qué te refieres con la ruta no actual?

Answer (score 1):

Aunque la pregunta no es muy clara creo que lo que quieres son todas las posibles rutas. Para hacerlo puedes utilizar la función `Route::getRoutes()` que te devuelve una lista con todas las rutas.

```
$routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
```

Ahora ya las tienes todas en `routeCollection` y si quieres iterar por ellas:

```
foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
    echo $value->getPath();
}
```

Por lo que el código entero sería:

```
$routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
    echo $value->getPath();
}
```